# swig wrapping Issues with c++ templates

Tags: c++, python, swig, swig-template

I have a swig file which contains the following code:

```
%module vgSofa

#define VG_SOFA_API

%import vgd/vgd.i
%import vgm/vgm.i


%template(BasicHandlerShp1) boost::shared_ptr<vgSofa::handler::BasicHandler>;


%{

#include "vgSofa/handler/BasicHandler.hpp"

%}

%template(BasicHandlerShp) vgd::Shp<vgSofa::handler::BasicHandler>;


%include "vgSofa/handler/BasicHandler.hpp"
```

Where `vgd::Shp` inherits to `boost::shared_ptr`.
This code generates the wrapper and python file but in the python file generated I don't have access to `vgSofa::handler::BasicHandler` functions in my template `BasicHandlerShp`.
How can I do to access these functions in `BasicHandlerShp` ?
Thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

Does the BasicHandlerShp1 class work for you?  I'm not sure why you would want vgd::Shp to inherit from shared_ptr, is that really what you want to do?